# ASP.NET Core MVC project appears to add AntiForgery tokens automatically?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, csrf, asp.net-core-mvc

Using the out-of-the-box MVC app created by the most recent (RC2) VS2015 ASP.NET Core template, the file _LoginPartial.cshtml is rendered as a partial in the shared _Layout.cshtml file.  _LoginPartial has the following content:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using CodeServer.Models

@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="LogOff" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Log off</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">Log in</a></li>
    </ul>
}
```

When this is rendered into the page, this is the result (from view source):

```
<form method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right" action="/Account/LogOff">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            <a title="Manage" href="/Manage">Hello user@email.com!</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Log off</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="..." /></form>
```

Not to be ungracious to ASP.NET, but how is that token getting in there?  I furthermore did a find-in-files for the whole solution on AntiForgery, and the only hits are either `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` tags or entries in project.lock.json.

I wanted to verify that my validate tags were working by intentionally leaving out the token in the request, but I can't do that when the token is helpfully(?) added for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Not to be ungracious to ASP.NET, but how is that token getting in there?

The antiforgery token you're seeing is automagically generated and added by [`FormTagHelper`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/FormTagHelper.cs).

You can disable this automatic feature by adding the `asp-antiforgery="false"` attribute:

```
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="LogOff" asp-antiforgery="false" 
      method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

To disable AntiForgery Token everywhere in your project, add this code to your Application_Start method in the Global.asax file.

```
AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressIdentityHeuristicChecks = true
```